# Clone a python selenium phantomJS instance to process multiple pages after executing actions

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium to automate tasks on a wide variety of websites. Everything that I want to do works fine, except there is a lot of repeated work.

For example, imagine that I you filled out a form on a search page. The search results page gives you something like this:

```
1. Result1
2. Result2
3. Result3

> Next page
```

Where all of `Result1`, `Result2`, `Result3` and `> Next page` are links with information that I care about.

Ideally, I want to get the page source of all results, and exhaust all pagination links as well.

Currently, my flow is something like this:

```
- Get search page
- Fill out and submit form
- Click link 1
- Return page Source

- Get search page
- Fill out and submit form
- Click link 2
- Return page source

...

- Get search page
- Fill out and submit form
- Click next page link
- Click link for Result 1 on next page
- Return source
```

Obviously, there is way too much repeated work here. Ideally, I would like to clone my browser so that I could have a flow like this:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(search_page)
# fill out and submit form, wait for results
links = extract_links(browser.page_source)
sources = [browser.page_source]
for link in links:
    browser_clone = clone(browser)
    click link in browser_clone
    sources.append(browser_clone.page_source)
return sources
```

The problem that I have here is with `browser_clone = clone(browser)`. `deepcopy` doesn't work, as it will effect `browser`. I can't `pickle` the browser, because it is not supposed for webdriver elements. Is there any way to do this?